# Align text within bordered div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align text vertically and horizontally within a rounded div (with a border radius). I tried tags like `position:absolute` and `relative`

I tried adding this :

```
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
```

in my CSS but I had no success.

Below is the snippet. I wonder what the optimal solution would be without adding other divs. Thanks in advance.

```css
.card-container2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
margin:auto;
align-contents:center;
    }

.card-container {

cursor: pointer;
  height: 350px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
    border-radius: 50%;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

-moz-animation-name: dropCard;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.3s;

    -webkit-animation-name: dropCard;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.3s;

    animation-name: dropCard;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;

}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background:#000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .back {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


@-moz-keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }

  100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<div class="card-container2">
<div class="card-container">
<div class="card">
<div class="side" style="text-align: center;"><img class="displayed" src="IMAGE" alt="" width="350" height="350" /></div>
<div class="side back">
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000;">Campaign Name: 11111111&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Campaign Dates:&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">333333333333333 -&nbsp;22222222222&nbsp;</span></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Length of campaign:4444444444444&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Days left of campaign:&nbsp;55555555555555555}&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about if the text doesn't fit the circle ??? if overflows?

Comment: @Paulie_D His problem is **PRETTY CLEAR** to understand. He wants the text inside the circle to fit the circle border.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am guessing there is a competition issue with the ratings here. It is pretty clear what I want. The text to align WITHIN the CIRCLED div (rounded). Next time I will spend days to find a solution and ask giving an answer to make ti clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulie_D "align" without mentioning if I want it vertically, horizontally.... That means I need both. That's what I would understand. For example for the margin tag in the CSS... we say margin:0 . We do not mention left right bottom top. I hope you understand why I did not clarify if I need hor-ver. Cheers

Comment: @Paulie_D Guessing? Hmmm. 3 people answered. 3 good answers given . No offence but this is crazy. Especially, downvoting for "unclear" questions. Also, I have not mentioned the overflow thing yet. I might do if I need it.

Comment: He clearly stated that he needs to align text in center even he added three lines of codes which show text-align:center. Okay now while running his codes contents were going outside div, so it's quiet clear that he needs them to be vertically align to div.

Comment: @Paulie_D 39834574 has an update in the question. There was no other way to reach out with you. I had to answer here. I also have a solution (answer) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your plan is to align text within `backside rounded div .back .side` properly in center, then remove margin from `<p> tag` and add `padding-top` to `.back`

```
.card .back {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  padding-top:75px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
p{
  margin:5px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```css
.card-container2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
margin:auto;
align-contents:center;
    }

.card-container {

cursor: pointer;
  height: 350px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
    border-radius: 50%;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

-moz-animation-name: dropCard;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.3s;

    -webkit-animation-name: dropCard;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.3s;

    animation-name: dropCard;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;

}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background:#000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .back {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  padding-top:75px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
p{
  margin:5px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}


@-moz-keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }

  100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<div class="card-container2">
<div class="card-container">
<div class="card">
<div class="side" style="text-align: center;"><img class="displayed" src="IMAGE" alt="" width="350" height="350" /></div>
<div class="side back">
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000;">Campaign Name: 11111111&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Campaign Dates:&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">333333333333333 -&nbsp;22222222222&nbsp;</span></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Length of campaign:4444444444444&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Days left of campaign:&nbsp;55555555555555555}&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `padding` of 10% to `.card .back`

```css
.card-container2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
margin:auto;
align-contents:center;
    }

.card-container {

cursor: pointer;
  height: 350px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
    border-radius: 50%;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

-moz-animation-name: dropCard;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.3s;

    -webkit-animation-name: dropCard;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.3s;

    animation-name: dropCard;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;

}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background:#000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .back {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000;
  padding:10%;
  line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


@-moz-keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }

  100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes dropCard {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<div class="card-container2">
<div class="card-container">
<div class="card">
<div class="side" style="text-align: center;"><img class="displayed" src="IMAGE" alt="" width="350" height="350" /></div>
<div class="side back">
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000;">Campaign Name: 11111111&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Campaign Dates:&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">333333333333333 -&nbsp;22222222222&nbsp;</span></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Length of campaign:4444444444444&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Days left of campaign:&nbsp;55555555555555555}&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS just after your `.card .back` line..

```
.back>p:first-child {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

EDIT:
Also you can reduce the line height in `.card .back` to prevent overflow. I reduced it to 20px. Seemed to fit better, but that is a matter of preference..

Answer (score 0):

Since the requirement is, *as mentioned in the comments*, to center the content in the circle vertically and horizontally, we can use flexbox for that.

Like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.card-container2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.card-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 350px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
}
.card .back {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container2">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="side" style="text-align: center;">
        <img class="displayed" src="IMAGE" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
      </div>
      <div class="side back">
        <p><span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000;">Campaign Name: 11111111&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Campaign Dates:&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">333333333333333 -&nbsp;22222222222&nbsp;</span></span>
        </p>
        <p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Length of campaign:4444444444444&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span style="color: #000; font-size: 14pt;">Days left of campaign:&nbsp;55555555555555555&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this does not address any *overflow* issues as you can see.

Comment: What would you add to avoid overflow?

Comment: I'd split the spans into two.. one for the text and one for the numbers.

Comment: Did that. But if the 111111 is very long. I will need to make it stop. The font-size (vw) does not always help here.

Comment: There are way to break long strings into sections but I'm not sure they apply here. Is the number *really* going to be that long...or is there some other text you were planning on putting in there?

Comment: Other text. And I have gotten a confirmation that it will be long.

Comment: I disagree with you for the question syntax but I also disagree with the person who downvoted this answer. It is not a revenge issue :P I hope the person who did this sees that.